# Is there a keyboard shortcut for playing a song next in iTunes DJ?

Tags: itunes, keyboard

I would like a quicker method of queuing up my songs in iTunes DJ. Right clicking and selecting the option is too slow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't mention what keyboard, but on the Apple keyboard:

F7 - restart current song

F8 - pause/play

F9 - skip forward

Note that you need to have the box unchecked in OSX that says use function keys as normal. In the event you use your function keys for something, I've also successfully created trigger hotkey combos in Quicksilver. You can also probably just remap them in keyboard preferences.

Comment: Sorry, that isn't what I meant. I want to be able to quickly queue up songs into the iTunes DJ

Comment: If I understand you correctly, that's probably going to be hard with a hotkey, because you'd need someway to select the songs you want to add and then hit the hotkey to add them. iTunes DJ does a pretty good job of adding songs automatically for me so it's endless. If you want to delve more into iTunes, you'll need to play with AppleScript..you can start here. http://dougscripts.com/itunes/itinfo/info01.php

Comment: That looks like it can do it

Answer (score 1):

You can make an automator workflow with "Get Selected iTunes Tracks" and "Add Songs to Playlist". That will add it to the end of iTunes DJ, though, is that good enough?

In order to give it a keyboard shortcut, you can either use a keyboard shortcut utility like Spark, Quicksilver, or Butler, or you can save the workflow as a service and give it a shortcut in the keyboard shortcuts section of the system preferences.

Comment: I would prefer to add them to the front of the queue, but that solution could be workable

Answer (score 0):

I have made two Automator workflows that do what mckeed suggested. They take the selected tracks and put them in the iTunes DJ list.
Put [these](http://www.mediafire.com/?by7qj5k3uvllg9d) two files in the `/Users/[Username]/Library/Services` folder and then you can assign keyboard shortcuts through the system preferences to them.
The `Add to iTunes DJ` service just adds the selected track to the end of the queue, the `Add to iTunes DJ and Play` does the same, but starts playing the song right away.